# Blueimp Jquery File Upload / PHP - Session ID variable not passing through to script

Tags: php, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Long story short, I've been at this for quite a bit. I am teaching myself PHP, so please bear with any ignorance and I will happily clarify any and everything.

I'm using Blueimp's Jquery File Uploader and I'm having trouble having the uploader insert the uploaded files into the appropriate users' folder which I have set to be created automatically at registration. The JFU's native user directory ability does not work for me because all uploads are placed into the same session folder, a string of seemingly miscellaneous alphanumeric characters which I'm assuming is being read as the randomized session ID. So what I am trying to do is change the session to read as the logged-in username, and use that as its ID. I've scoured the internet and found various resources, but nothing has yet worked for me. Everything gets uploaded to the parent /uploads/ folder, but not the username-specific subfolders.

Previous post:

[PHP Jquery File Upload // Username/Session Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122653/php-jquery-file-upload-username-session-directories)

(Some) Sources:

-[How to get/set session_id() or should it be generated automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068791/how-to-get-set-session-id-or-should-it-be-generated-automatically)

-[Jquery File Upload change session id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613238/jquery-file-upload-change-session-id)

Using the advice given on my previous post, I still encounter the "Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error, which I'm assuming means that the $username variable is failing to be defined/passed through.

The current login/session process is set at login, persists through pages, and exists as $loggedInUser->username (prints logged-in username on pages when called) and the session is read as $_SESSION['user_name']. I have tried applying every mix and match I can think of to the various sources I have found, and nothing seems to read the variable and insert the files into the appropriate user folders. Is there a way to tell the script to either read the session or read from database as the username, then upload into that username's folder?

My current code is as follows:

index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($username);
```

UploadHandler.php

```
function __construct($username, $options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/../../uploads/'.$username.'/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/../../uploads/'.$username.'/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: is it whole code? if Yes so where You're starting session? session_start(); $username = $_SESSION['user_name']; require('UploadHandler.php');

Comment: This is a complex utility, but basically you need to subclass the `UploadHandler` and override the standard method funtionality to achieve what you are tring to do. If you are not up on OOP you will get very lost very quickly.

Comment: @num8er  At the head of my pages, I have require calls, one being config.php which is what reads the user settings and session calls. -- session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) && is_object($_SESSION["user_name"])) { $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["user_name"]; } – I tried adding your comment to my index.php file, but no progress.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got very lost. Very quickly.

Comment: Use: global $loggedInUser; to get variable from global scope.

Comment: @num8er Where do I input that code?

Comment: Before require('UploadHandler.php');

Comment: @num8er The $loggedInUser variable is still failing to be defined. I'm trying to keep up but I'm afraid that I'm failing to see the forest for the trees. 
`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
global $loggedInUser;
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($loggedInUser);`

Comment: Include config.php before global